# Using HTML Template and Jquery clone to add new panels onto div

Tags: jquery, html

I have this simple html template

```
<template id="templateDefaultPanel">
    <div class="panel panel-default"> 
        <div class="panel-heading"> 
            <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3> 
        </div> 
        <div class="panel-body"> 
            Panel content 
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

I am cloning it using jquery `var $panelTemplate = $("#templateDefaultPanel").clone();` and then modifiying the inner html `$panelTemplate.find('.panel-body').html('hey there');` and then setting it to prepend on to another div `$('#allNotes').prepend($panelTemplate.html());` the problem is none of $panelTemplate content gets modified. And then when i try `prependTo` the template is inserted which of course does not show to the user.

When I switch out template to div all my above code works, though whats the point of templates if i can't reuse the html and you know templating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to clone the template, as you want the content of the template, not the template it self, so you could do it with `innerHTML`

if you look at vanilla js example it makes more sense, as you work with `.content` not `template`

```
const template = document.querySelector('#templateDefaultPanel');

template.content.querySelector('.panel-title').innerHTML = 'hello world';
template.content.querySelector('.panel-body').innerHTML = 'the body here';

const clone = document.importNode(template.content, true);
document.querySelector('#allNotes').appendChild(clone);
```

so you dont work with the template it self but the contents of it, so one way of doing this with jQuery could be

```
const $template = $( $('#templateDefaultPanel')[0].innerHTML );
// or alternatively get the content with .prop('content')

$template.find('.panel-title').html('hello world');
$template.find('.panel-body').html('the body here');

$('#allNotes').append($template);
```

Answer (score 1):

After all you have to create a div container and add the template content to it and then prepend the div element. Template elements won't be rendered at all.
See:
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template

There is also an example.

Answer (score 1):

While I see that there is already an accepted answer for this question, if you really want/need to use the jQuery `clone()` method -- perhaps because you also want to include the data-and-events via `clone(true)` -- then you can't use the `<template>` element for what you're cloning.

I don't know why and I have not seen any documentation to indicate why, but if you `clone()` a `<template>` then **no other jQuery methods will work against the cloned jQuery object**.

So the `<template>` element seems to be less useful than a hidden `<div>` in terms of jQuery usage and that's likely what I'll use unless I can `clone()` the **contents** of the `<template>`.

On a side-note, using `clone()` on a `<template>` element actually works in IE but not in any of the so-called 'modern browsers'.  Likely this is because IE doesn't treat `<template>` any differently than any other element but the others do...